# Correct http verb to use for login API

Tags: http, rest

What would be the "correct HTTP verb" to use when developing a RESTful API to handle login information? This API would be accessible from various devices/platforms - mobile app, desktop web app, desktop native app, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that by API Login you mean a way to authenticate an API user and any calls to your API endpoints.

You could probably use OAuth or Basic Authentication to do that or let say you have an API endpoint at `api\authenticate`. The caller would `POST` to this endpoint with userID and password or some API key. The service would then return a cookie or authentication token that would be sent with every call to other API endpoints. The [HP Cloud Identity service](https://api-docs.hpcloud.com/hpcloud-identity-service/1.0/content/authenticate.html) works pretty much the same way.

Comment: Thanks, but why POST? Is that syntatically correct in terms of REST mappings for HTTP verbs? Or must it be POST purely for convenience?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa, REST is not necessarily about 'mappings' to HTTP verbs, but it basically states that an interface should be uniform with self descriptive messages. RFC 2616 defines POST as a method for creating subordinate resources or submitting blocks of data for processing (as a general purpose method.) In this case, using POST would be pretty uniform and general purpose for authentication.

Comment: if you are working directly with base authentication and user passwords, don't forget to somehow encrypt the POST parameters over the wire (or just use SSL).